# canberra distance - inconsistent results

Tags: r, distance

I'm trying to understand what's going on with my calculation of canberra distance. I write my own simple `canberra.distance` function, however the results are not consistent with `dist` function. I added option `na.rm = T` to my function, to be able calculate the sum when there is zero denominator. From `?dist` I understand that they use similar approach: `Terms with zero numerator and denominator are omitted from the sum and treated as if the values were missing.`

```
canberra.distance <- function(a, b){
  sum( (abs(a - b)) / (abs(a) + abs(b)), na.rm = T )
}

a <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
b <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
canberra.distance(a, b)
> 3 
# the result that I expected
dist(rbind(a, b), method = "canberra")
> 3.75 


a <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
b <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)
canberra.distance(a, b)
> 3
# the result that I expected
dist(rbind(a, b), method = "canberra")
> 4   

a <- c(0, 1, 0)
b <- c(1, 0, 1)
canberra.distance(a, b)
> 3
dist(rbind(a, b), method = "canberra")
> 3
# now the results are the same
```

Pairs 0-0 and 1-1 seem to be problematic. In the first case (0-0) both numerator and denominator are equal to zero and this pair should be omitted. In the second case (1-1) numerator is 0 but denominator is not and the term is then also 0 and the sum should not change.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
To be in line with R definition, function `canberra.distance` can be modified as follows:

```
canberra.distance <- function(a, b){
  sum( abs(a - b) / abs(a + b), na.rm = T )
}
```

However, the results are the same as before.

Comment: I think you may have stumbled upon a bug in base R. I’m not sure, but [Wolfram Alpha agrees with you](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CanberraDistance%5B%7B1,+0,+1,+0%7D,+%7B0,+1,+0,+0%7D%5D). Unfortunately I can’t find an authoritative reference but your implementation seems correct according to Wikipedia and Wolfram.

Comment: In fact, the [documentation of `dist`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/dist.html) defines the Canberra distance as *sum(|x_i - y_i| / |x_i + y_i|)* (which differs from yours and Wolfram’s). It also notes that “[t]his is intended for non-negative values (e.g., counts): taking the absolute value of the denominator is a 1998 R modification to avoid negative distances.” — So R’s definition is documented to be different.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank for your reply! I edited my post. With R definition of canberra distance inconsistencies remain so I do not think this is the problem.

Comment: Yes, I’m suspecting that the “1998 R modification” that the documentation mentions is more than just removing the negative values. In effect, the documentation may be intended to say “this implementation differs from other definitions in an unspecified way and consequently yields different results”. A look at the C source could clarify this. At any rate, it’s poorly documented at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

This might shed some light on the difference. As far as I can see this is the actual code being run for computing the distance

```
static double R_canberra(double *x, int nr, int nc, int i1, int i2)
{
    double dev, dist, sum, diff;
    int count, j;

    count = 0;
    dist = 0;
    for(j = 0 ; j < nc ; j++) {
    if(both_non_NA(x[i1], x[i2])) {
        sum = fabs(x[i1] + x[i2]);
        diff = fabs(x[i1] - x[i2]);
        if (sum > DBL_MIN || diff > DBL_MIN) {
        dev = diff/sum;
        if(!ISNAN(dev) ||
           (!R_FINITE(diff) && diff == sum &&
            /* use Inf = lim x -> oo */ (int) (dev = 1.))) {
            dist += dev;
            count++;
        }
        }
    }
    i1 += nr;
    i2 += nr;
    }
    if(count == 0) return NA_REAL;
    if(count != nc) dist /= ((double)count/nc);
    return dist;
}
```

I think the culprit is this line

```
if(!ISNAN(dev) ||
               (!R_FINITE(diff) && diff == sum &&
                /* use Inf = lim x -> oo */ (int) (dev = 1.)))
```

which handles a special case and may not be documented.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm not really skilled in C++ so I'm not sure what's going on with these special cases. Could you please shed some light on it?

Comment: The line contains the special case that if the two values are identical `diff == sum` then it adds one to the numerator since it sets `dev=1`. However, why the code gets past `diff > DBL_MIN` in the first place is a bit unclear to me. Perhaps there is a problems with floating point conversion/precision?

Comment: Well, adding one to the numerator would explain the case of 1-1 pair and the distance value of 4. However I can't see how this involve case of 0-0 pair. Any idea?

Comment: For the 0-0 pair the sum is zero and the difference is also zero so the `diff == sum` part still triggers.